# Error parsing data java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, arrays, android-listview

In the loop, 'm' works from 0 to 4 but then crashes, instead of going from 0 to 6.

```
ArrayList<ItemTeacher> results = new ArrayList<ItemTeacher>();
String resultteacher="";
String[] binku2=null;

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://"+localip+":8080/Apj/Teacher_Servlet");

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream is = entity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line);
    }
    is.close();
    resultteacher = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("RESULT is : -**********"+resultteacher+"********-");


    String[] binku = resultteacher.split("@");

    System.out.println("LENGTH OF BINKU = "+binku.length);

    for(int m=0;m<=binku.length-1;m++)
    {

        binku2 = binku[m].split("#");
        System.out.println("Record number"+binku2[m]);
        drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://"+localip+":8080/Apj/TeacherImage/"+binku2[4]+".png");
        System.out.println("IMAGE DATA DISPLAY ="+drawable);

        ItemTeacher item_teacher = new ItemTeacher();

        item_teacher.setname(binku2[0]);
            item_teacher.setinfo(binku2[1]);
            item_teacher.setimage(drawable);
            String binku3[] = binku2[2].split("~");
            String binku4[] = binku2[3].split("~");

            String time="";
            String timeroom="";
            time =("Lecture Timings - Classroom");
            for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
            {
            //  time +=("[Timings and Room]");
                timeroom +=("["+binku3[i]+" - "+binku4[i]+"]"+"      ");
                //System.out.println("Record number"+binku3[i]);
            }
            item_teacher.settime(time);
            item_teacher.setroom(timeroom);
            System.out.println("m value is ="+m);

            results.add(item_teacher);

    }
}


catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}

return results;
}
```

Logcat details:

```
02-12 21:33:36.772: I/System.out(358): RESULT is : -**********Mrs Roopali Sood#M.C.M (Head IT Dept)#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#F8~Lab 1~Lab 3~F7~F8~S9~Free~S8~F8~#1@Mr Jagmohan Mago#M.C.A (IT Dept).#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#Free~S2~F8~S1~F9~Free~Lab 2~S9~Lab1~#2@Mr Munish Gupta#M.C.A (IT Dept).#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#S9~F8~S1~Lab 1~F1~Free~F8~Lab 3~S5~#3@Mrs Pallavi Chopra#M.C.A., M.Phil. (IT Dept).#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#Lab 2~Free~S2~F8~Free~Free~Lab 2~Free~Lab1~#4@Mr Abhejeet Singh#M.C.A (IT Dept).#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#Lab 3~Lab 1~Lab 3~S7~F8~Lab 2~Free~S8~S9~#5@Vinay#M.C.A (IT Dept).#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#Free~S2~F8~S1~F9~Free~Lab 2~S9~Lab1~#6@Bharti#Pata nai#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#S9~F8~S1~Lab 1~F1~Free~F8~Lab 3~S5~#7@********-
02-12 21:33:36.784: I/System.out(358): LENGTH OF BINKU = 7
02-12 21:33:36.784: I/System.out(358): Record numberMrs Roopali Sood
02-12 21:33:37.082: I/System.out(358): IMAGE DATA DISPLAY =android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4618b990
02-12 21:33:37.102: I/System.out(358): m value is =0
02-12 21:33:37.102: I/System.out(358): Record numberM.C.A (IT Dept).
02-12 21:33:37.512: I/System.out(358): IMAGE DATA DISPLAY =android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4619c2a8
02-12 21:33:37.522: I/System.out(358): m value is =1
02-12 21:33:37.522: I/System.out(358): Record number9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~
02-12 21:33:37.772: I/System.out(358): IMAGE DATA DISPLAY =android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@461ac610
02-12 21:33:37.782: I/System.out(358): m value is =2
02-12 21:33:37.792: I/System.out(358): Record numberLab 2~Free~S2~F8~Free~Free~Lab 2~Free~Lab1~
02-12 21:33:38.102: I/System.out(358): IMAGE DATA DISPLAY =android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@461bca98
02-12 21:33:38.112: I/System.out(358): m value is =3
02-12 21:33:38.112: I/System.out(358): Record number5
02-12 21:33:38.492: I/System.out(358): IMAGE DATA DISPLAY =android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@461ccc80
02-12 21:33:38.492: I/System.out(358): m value is =4
02-12 21:33:38.505: I/System.out(358): Error parsing data java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly not what you are intending:

```
binku2 = binku[m].split("#");
System.out.println("Record number"+binku2[m]);
```

You seem to operate everywhere as though the `binku2` array will be of length 4, but then you attempt to access an index with the value of `m`. Thus, when you hit the 5th iteration of the loop, `m` is 4 and you throw the exception. Probably you meant to access `binku` here:

```
binku2 = binku[m].split("#");
System.out.println("Record number"+binku[m]);
```

Comment: yes may be out of loop but i don't know how ?
from database there are 7 values coming and it is showing only 5 i.e  0 to 4

Comment: There are 7 values in `binku`, not in `binku2`. Re-read my post: it looks like you're accessing the *wrong array* at that line.

Comment: no binku2 is for spliting the values of binku
but i access binku for running loop from 0 to 7-1
but it is running 0 to 4

Data 
Mrs Roopali Sood#M.C.M (Head IT Dept)#9:00~9:45~10:30~10:45~11:30~12:15~1:00~1:45~3:30~#F8~Lab 1~Lab 3~F7~F8~S9~Free~S8~F8~#1@

Comment: You're still not understanding what I'm saying. **How many items to you expect binku2 to have?** Right now you're accessing it at index `m`, which is based on the length of `binku` **not** the length of `binku2`. What happens if `binku` has 100 items? Then `m` will increase to 99 and you'll try to read a value at `binku2[99]`. Will that work? Your code seems to indicate "no".

Comment: i binku is 100 times the 100 values of data entry will show in list

Comment: @android_guy: I really don't know how else to explain it. You're trying to read the wrong array at that line. I can pretty much guarantee that's where the exception is being thrown. If you change `System.out.println("Record number"+binku2[m]);` to `System.out.println("Record number"+binku[m]);` it'll probably work (or throw an error somewhere else). I fully comprehend that `binku` can have 100 values, but *that's not the array you're printing the value from*.

Comment: thanks dude for cooperation i will try to apply the fact you are saying lets see

Answer (score 1):

You are setting yourself up for errors by hard coding your loops like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<=8;i++)
```

You should always use dynamic values like `m<=binku.length-1` or the simpler version `m < binku.length`. And when you are working with more than one array it is safest to check each array's length:

```
for(int i = 0; i < binku3.length && i < binku4.length; i++)
```

Comment: It's actually reading from `binku3` and `binku4` at that point.

Comment: length of binku is 7 ie 0 to 6 (7-1) 
it works from 0 to 4 only

Comment: @eldarerathis Indeed, I think there is a wealth of errors to be found, I'll amend my answer but leave it up as general advice.

Comment: Yes, either way your point is entirely valid (and may very well cause an exception itself)